# Is it possible to setup VPN on dedicated server, while having Web server nginx, mysql and other services to access blocked Websites from home?

Tags: linux, networking, debian, vpn, openvpn

I have an dedicated server with 1 static IP and 2 additional static IP addresses.

The OS installed is Linux, Debian 9 x64.

I wonder if there is a possibility to setup openVPN or something else as VPN, so I can access blocked Websites through my dedicated server as VPN?.

Is that possible?

Or do I need to make some port forwarding?

I do not need for multiple users, just for me to connect to it and browse the Website which I cannot access from home using Windows OS.

Do I have to install OpenVZ on my dedicated server? What next and what else if so?

Thank you four suggestions and ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is yes you can. Check out the [debian man page](https://wiki.debian.org/OpenVPN) for OpenVPN. You will need the client side on your home computer. Everything you need is on that page. Failing that OVH offer an OpenVPN solution and is configured through the GUI. Total breeze.